# how to achieve time-shift functionality using tshark?

Tags: tshark

I want to print captured packets using tshark. However I want to use "time-shift" functionality in tshark (which is readily available in wireshark GUI). I couldn't find any relevant information in --help menu. Any possible guidance is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As follow-up information I could find editcap -t functionality, which serves my purpose. Marking this as closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follow-up input I could find `editcap -t` functionality, which serves my purpose. Marking this as closed